# How to get JVM Heap Size of Running Spring Boot (Spring Web MVC) API (runtime)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, amazon-ecs, docker-container

I have a Spring Boot API hosted on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) running inside a Docker container. I am using a **m5.xlarge** instance which has `4 vCPUs` and `16GB on physical RAM` on the cluster. I was currently fine-tuning CPU and Memory, but finding it very random and tedious, despite following this article:
https://medium.com/@vlad.fedosov/how-to-calculate-resources-reservation-for-ecs-task-3c68a1e12725

I'm still a little confused on what to set the JVM heap size too. From what I read, Java 10+ allows for automatic detection of container and will set the JVM to 25% of the Container RAM (Or is this the actually physical RAM of the Cluster??), ***however***, I am using Java8

I am logging the garbage collections logs via VM arguments:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:${LOG_DIR}/gc.log -
```

My questions are -

1. What is the easiest way to get the JVM Heap size my app is using at runtime? Is there a command, a tool etc...?
2. I am running Java8 which I believe does NOT detect container and will set JVM based on PHYSICAL SERVER RAM - I am using a m5.xlarge instance on AWS with 4 vCPUs and 16GB RAM, so if I didn't specific `-Xms` or `-Xmx` JVM heap size would be 16GB * 0.25 = 4GB correct??
3. If my container memory/task on AWS ECS is 120% currently, how do I know if that is the JVM heap OR container memory that is the problem/too low OR maybe even my application code being inefficient? This is an API and it is querying the Database many thousand times per minute so many Objects are floating around residually in memory and not being garbage collected?? I'm not sure, but would appreciate any help

Comment: `Runtime#totalMemory` and `Runtime#freeMemory`?

Comment: The option UseContainerSupport was backported to Java 8u191 and activated by default: https://merikan.com/2019/04/jvm-in-a-container/#backported-to-java-8

Comment: `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` is often useful to describe your Heap memory needs in a dynamic way (the default is 25%).

Comment: `jcmd` is a versatile tool that you can use to get a lot of information about  the running JVM process - the list of supported options depends on the JDK version but it can typically get details about heap as well as off-heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. and 3. You'll have the data in log file you've specified in ${LOG_DIR}/gc.log
   TIP: use gc_%t.log to grab all of gc logs (not only the last one) and write them to persistance storage.
   You can visualise the data e.g. at gceasy.io - you'll see entire heap - collections, times, etc.

But remember your app is not only heap, it's also off heap - and it's not so easy to track off heap (eg native memory tracking is consuming additional resources, etc.) - the easiest way is to grab threaddump (the fastest way but not the recommended on PROD env is to build your app with JDK, run jstack command in app terminal and redirect it to file on persistent storage). Then you can also visualise it at https://fastthread.io/

2. it depends which update eg [blog](https://blog.softwaremill.com/docker-support-in-new-java-8-finally-fd595df0ca54)
   especialy note vm flag XX:***RAMPercentage

Start investigating your app - gc.log if you'll see nothing suspicious then you'll need to check your container utilization.

Comment: Oh I didn't know gc.log had also the Heap information

Comment: Heap information you can find in heapdump, but before grabbing heapdump there is gc triggered. But inf gc.log you can find what size is used, pauses time, etc.